# Difference between flutter logs command and IDE debug window

Tags: android, ios, flutter, logging

When you have a Flutter project open in Android Studio or VSCode, and you run it (either on a real device or emulator), you have a debug window available where you can see your print messages.

Does the "flutter logs" command show the exact same thing as this?

If not, what accounts for the difference?

Answer (score 0):

The **"flutter logs"** command is used to display **log output in the terminal**, while the **IDE debug window** is used to **display log output in the integrated development environment (IDE) such as Android Studio or Visual Studio Code**. **The "flutter logs"** command is useful for viewing log output when running the app from the **command line**, **while the IDE debug window** is **useful for viewing log output when running the app from within the IDE**. Both of these tools display the **same log output**, **but in different locations**.

Comment: I hope it's help you to understand about flutter logs command and IDE debug window. Happy coding :}